# how to develop features delivered by drupal if there is no cms

Tags: 7

I'm quite familiar with drupal, had done a few projects using drupal. I had an interview where the interviewer asked a few unexpected questions (atleast for me they were like unexpected!!). Few of them were

> How do you develop the same features that you did, if there is no CMS
>   (Drupal)?
>
> What tables/scheme (mysql) do you create to generate all possible
>   fields??
>
> If you are going to attach a pdf file (corresponding to each record)
>   where do you specify that pdf file, do you use sql table or else
>   what??

These were a few questions that I couldn't explain with full confidence.

I didn't even thought of the process behind drupal. I just used to work with my requirements and needs, I never thought of what the process might be. And more specifically with sql.

Do any of you have any views?

Comment: I can't see anything related to Drupal in your question (in fact the opposite, it's specifically _not_ about Drupal). If I've got that wrong please edit to make it clear what you need to know about Drupal, and it can be reopened. Thanks

Comment: To add to what @Clive said, we don't share views or opinions: We answer questions about Drupal. Asking how you would implement something without using Drupal is clearly not a Drupal question, which is not a question containing the word _Drupal_.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is easy.

> How do you develop the same features that you did, if there is no CMS
>   (Drupal)?

With a MVC framework like Symfony, CakePHP or Zen.

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal as a [Content Management Framework](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/before/overview) you could develop a site without using any of the CMS features.

Each entity has base fields (attributes) attached to the same table. Besides the base table, entities can have other supporting tables, such as revision, hierarchy, roles, or whatever the entity needs to make it tick. When you create a bundle and attach new fields, each attached field has its own database table, as well as its own revision table.

Attaching a file field to a bundle will require the 2 tables as mentioned. I addition, Drupal also keeps other information about the files in the system which is stored in other tables, such as file_managed and file_usage tables, reason being File is also an entity in Drupal, though slightly lacking in features in Drupal 7 (that is why contrib [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity)) exist.